# Sellers in a certain amount wont stack

Tags: c#, loops, foreach

Im sorting sellers in a data table. If a seller reach a curtain amount it will stand "Amount of sellers in lvl 4 is "X" ".

If I print the values for my if-statments it works. I get 1 salesman in each label for all my levels.

Now the problem is that if another salesman has the same amount the label wont update and it will still stand that 1 seller has reached that amount.

```
foreach (DataRow Drow in information.Rows)
{
    int num = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = Drow["Namn"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = Drow["Personnummer"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = Drow["Distrikt"].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[3].Value = Drow["Antal artiklar"];

    WhatLevel(salesman);
}
```

```cs
public void WhatLevel(Salesman sales)
{
    int levelOne = 0;
    int levelTwo = 0;
    int levelThree = 0;
    int levelFour = 0;
   
    if (sales.AmountSold < 50)
    {
        levelOne++;
        label8.Text = levelOne.ToString();
    }

    if (sales.AmountSold >= 50 && sales.AmountSold < 99)
    {
        levelTwo++;
        label12.Text = levelTwo.ToString();
    }

    if (sales.AmountSold >= 100 && sales.AmountSold < 199)
    {
        levelThree++;
        label13.Text = levelThree.ToString();
    }

    if (sales.AmountSold >= 199)
    {
        levelFour++;
        label14.Text = levelFour.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your question?

Comment: This is very difficult to understand. Try to remember that we have no knowledge of what you are working on besides what you're telling us.

Comment: Hello! Sorry for being inexplicit. Im creating a datatable of sellers. If they reach a surtain amount then it will stand "Amount of sellers in level 4 is: "X" "

I only get 1 seller in all my levels.

Comment: Sorry your problem description is still too vague. Could you please amend your question to describe the flow, what is the expected behaviour and what is the observed one? Could you also include all the necessary information to be able to [reproduce it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Otherwise we can't help.

Comment: Local variables, as in your `WhatLevel()` method, start fresh each time you call the method. If you want to implement your logic this way, you need to use the _same_ variables each time you call the method. See duplicate. Note that this isn't ideal either. See some of the other suggestions on this page for better ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined 4 local variables within the WhatLevel method. The scope of these 4 variables is limited to that method. Also, when the method is called, they are always initialized to zero before being incremented.

You'll have to do one of the following:

- Make the 4 level* variables be fields instead. That will preserve the value across calls to WhatLevel.
- If the WhatLevel method is only being called from within the foreach loop, move its content directly into the loop and avoid a separate method altogether, then place the declaration of the variables before the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Julius solution but i want to add some remarks.
You don't need to update label.Text in every iteration. You can do it at the end of the loop.

Based on single responsibility rule, i think it's better to add a property or a method to get level from salesman class.

finally use a collection to store number of level, imagine you have 10 or 20 levels.

I suggest this solution

Add a new property to the salesman class

```
public class Salesman
{
    public int AmountSold { get; set; }

    // Can be a method if you don't want to have property with a lot of code
    public int Level
    {
        get
        {
            if (AmountSold < 50)
            {
                return 1;
            }

            if (AmountSold >= 50 && AmountSold < 99)
            {
                return 2;
            }

            if (AmountSold >= 100 && AmountSold < 199)
            {
                return 3;
            }

            // AmountSold >= 199
            return 4;
        }
    }
}
```

Change implementation

```
        Dictionary<int, int> levelNumbers = new Dictionary<int, int>
        {
            { 1 , 0 },
            { 2 , 0 },
            { 3 , 0 },
            { 4 , 0 }
        };

        foreach (DataRow Drow in information.Rows)
        {
            int num = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[0].Value = Drow["Namn"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[1].Value = Drow["Personnummer"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[2].Value = Drow["Distrikt"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[num].Cells[3].Value = Drow["Antal artiklar"];

            levelNumbers[salesman.Level]++;
        }

        label8.Text = levelNumbers[1].ToString();
        label12.Text = levelNumbers[2].ToString();
        label13.Text = levelNumbers[3].ToString();
        label14.Text = levelNumbers[4].ToString();
```

If you want more flexibility and maybe lisibility you can use enum

```
public enum AmountSoldLevel
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four
}
```

In the class return AmountSoldLevel instead of int

```
public AmountSoldLevel Level
{
    get
    {
        if (AmountSold < 50)
        {
            return AmountSoldLevel.One;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

and init dictionary using

```
Dictionary<AmountSoldLevel, int> levelNumbers = new Dictionary<AmountSoldLevel, int>();
foreach (AmountSoldLevel amountSoldLevel in Enum.GetValues(typeof(AmountSoldLevel)))
{
   levelNumbers.Add(amountSoldLevel, 0);
}

// ...

label8.Text = levelNumbers[AmountSoldLevel.One].ToString();
label12.Text = levelNumbers[AmountSoldLevel.Two].ToString();
```

Sample test with app
[image: sample winform apps]